# Sorting a list with numbers in it:

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to sort a list:

```
x=['1', '3']
```

using x.sort()

I want it to sort in ascending order but when I print out the result I get "none"

```
x=['1', '3']
r=x.sort()
print(r)
```

Comment: BTW, you're sorting strings, not numbers. Use `x = ['1', '3', '10']`, sort it and look at the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sort` method *sorts* the elements *in-place (it modifies the existing list)* and *returns* `None`.

So, just print the `x` after using `sort`.

```
x = ['1', '3']
x.sort()
print(x)
```

If you want to *assign* the result to a *new* variable use `sorted`.